Does $\mathrm{REG_{CFG}} \leq_T \mathrm{HALTING}$?
Let $\mathrm{REG_{CFG}} = \{ G \text{ context-free grammar}\mid L(G) \text{ is regular} \}$.
Is it Turing-reducible to Halting problem?
Or say, is there a oracle machine with an oracle of Halting problem decides $\mathrm{REG_{CFG}}$?
I've found that $\mathrm{REG_{TM}} = \{ M \text{ Turing machine} \mid L(M) \text{ is regular} \}$ is $\Delta_3^0$-complete in the sense of Turing-reducible, so it cannot reduce to Halting problem. Does it help with my question?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
